# A php mail function regarding the additional parameters for headers

Tags: php

I'm using dreamhost for my mailing.
I'm having an issue with php mail function additional headers parameters.
This code works, and the email is sent:

```
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From: $name <**webmaster@example.com**>\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $name <**webmaster@example.com**>\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

but when I replace webmaster@example.com to the variable $email

```
$headers = "From: $name <**$email**>\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $name <**$email**>\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

The email doesn't get sent. I did do a print_r($_POST), and the elements are there. I also did another test where I typed the email: webmaster@example.com into the form, to see if it would send, and it did. So my question is, how do I remedy this issue, if a user types their email address into the form with another mailing extension, that mail will not get sent, but if the extension is @example.com, then the mail will get sent.

Answer (score 0):

$name variable should be the full emailaddress:

"$name = "  'a name'      email@whatever.com>   " 
   $headers = "From: $from \r\n";

works on my servers.   Add the leading < to the email addtress.  This system won't display the string at all if I include it.  If your form has different variables for the responders nam and email address you'll have to concatenate them to get $name in the right formate.

Comment: `$name = "name <name@example.org>";` - RFC2822